# How can I speed up datastax dse gremlin query 'find shortest path' between groups of nodes by adding timestamp index on edge

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, gremlin

I would like to speed up query by adding timeStamp property index on edge. but According to  the link :

http://www.datastax.com/2016/08/inside-dse-graph-what-powers-the-best-enterprise-graph-database

Vertex-centric indexes are spesific, But in my query I look for all edges between two groups of nodes and not specific.

so ,How can I speed the following query using timeStamp index on edge ?

```
ids1 = [{'~label=person',member_id=54666,community_id=505443455},{...},{...}]

ids2 = [{'~label=person',member_id=52366,community_id=501423455},{...},{...}]


g.V(ids1).repeat(timeLimit(20000).bothE().otherV().dedup().simplePath()).times(5).emit().where(hasId(within(ids2))).path().range(0,5)
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

can you provide more context with this?  how many id's are you passing ids1?  do you have an index built on the person vertex label?  have you tried using the .profile() method to see where bottlenecks exist in the traversal?

Comment: hello,I understood why my query so slow:

Comment: There is one "super node" which has 182,000 edges in the 3 hop in the path. how can I reduce the number of edges? ,my DB is huge. can I put timestamp solr index on edges ?

Comment: For example: A -[wrote_message(timeSpan...)]-> B OR   A-[Wrote_message]-> B(timeSpan) . what is the best way to put timestamp on edge or on the  vertex (B) ?       If I put timestamp on vertex B , it takes less disk space on SOLR index engine than put timestamp on edge.  In case my "find shortest path" query is : bothE().otherV() , where can I put the timestamp filter in order to reduce time query : on bothE or otherV() ?

Comment: But I would like to know how to improve the query by adding timeSpan on edge.: index('index_name').[outE('edgeLabel') | inE('edgeLabel') ].by('propertykey_name').add()

Comment: will it help to speed up[ performance if I user bothE().otherV()?